# Making message queues non-persistent in Linux

Tags: linux, persistence, message-queue

This may be a completely newbie question about message Queues, but we are having some issues with them being persistent across the Linux system. We are running Fedora 14 and using message queues to pass data to and from threads.

The problem is we create a message queue:

```
q = mq_open (strName, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_NONBLOCK, 0666, &sQAttr)
```

where:

```
strName = "/INFO_UPD_Q" or "/POLL_Q" ...
sQAttr.mq_flags   = 0;
sQAttr.mq_maxmsg  = iMaxNumMessages; /* 1 - 10 */
sQAttr.mq_msgsize = iSzOfMessages;
sQAttr.mq_curmsgs = 0;
```

The issue we are having is that as soon as we change the size of the messages passed or the app crashes/exits/aborts and the queues have not been closed and emptied, the next run of the programme floods the system with old messages or does not open correctly and data does not get to the threads.

At the moment we are solving the issue by changing the name of queues and then rebooting the system every so often.

How do we get the queues to stop doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: huh, I thought at first this would be about Qt. Please don't use non-common abbreviations. (edit: title was about "messageQs")

Comment: umm, not sure I am following? What non-common abbreviations would you be referring to? Thanks.

Comment: "messageQ" is an abbreviation which is not common. It causes confusion. Please avoid using uncommon abbreviations and parlance like that, if possible. I changed it to "message queue".

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks, will do in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the shell you can see all the existing queues using:

```
# ipcs -q
```

And you can remove stale queues:

```
# ipcrm -q MSQID
```

The MSQID is available from the output of the first command.